# JxBrowser How to get value from a html node within java

Tags: java, jxbrowser

Hello guys I am trying out the jxBrowser component and I am unable to the value of selected html component...

```
List<DOMElement> paragraphs = divRoot.findElements(By.cssSelector("p"));
            for (DOMElement paragraph : paragraphs) {
                System.out.println("paragraph.getNodeValue() = " +
                        paragraph.getNodeValue());
            }
```

I am able to find paragraphs.. But can't get their node's value.. or simply `<p>I cant get this value<p/>` The code must be okay because its just a pure copy of their own sample code: [here](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013714-query-selector)

So my question is... What have I done wrong? It seems properly imported.. I am using library version 6.19.1 on a macbook. ( And I even tried it on a windows 10 with same result.. )

Or if there is other java browser solution with similar functions.. What I need is to load a page, get some values out of some divs and then simulate click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMElement.getNodeValue()` returns the value of this node, depending on its `DOMNodeType`. The text you are trying to get is a children node for the

node, so you need to get it with the following code `paragraph.getChildren().get(0)`.

So, the final code will look like the following:

```
for (DOMElement paragraph : paragraphs) {
    System.out.println("paragraph.getNodeValue() = " +
    paragraph.getChildren().get(0).getNodeValue());
}
```